# How to compare double quotes in Clojure?

Tags: string, clojure

```
(= "\"" "\"")  ;; true

(let [ss "123\""]
  (doseq [s ss]
    (println s (= "\"" s) (.equals "\"" s))))

;; 1 false false
;; 2 false false
;; 3 false false
;; " false false
```

Why `false` in second case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the type of the elements given to you by `doseq`:

```
(let [ss "123\""]
  (doseq [s ss]
    (println (type s))))
```

You'll see that they're characters, yet you're comparing them against a string. That will always be false since the types don't match.

Compare against a character instead:

```
(let [ss "123\""]
  (doseq [s ss]
    (println s (= \" s)))) 

1 false
2 false
3 false
" true
```